# Nueva pregunta, error en ejecución | C

Tags: c

Código editado. Pero tengo un error nuevo...
Cuando el programa llega al final de los printf de Jugador 1 (los primeros printf), el programa se detiene y no me deja ingresar los datos de jugador 2, 3, 4 y 5. No avanza.

Intenté poner un fflush(stdin); antes del último scanf y tampoco hay solución.
Sugerencias...?

Este es mi código, ya edité el anterior que tenía varios errores y logré corregirlos por mi cuenta:

estoy añadiendo texto porque stackoverflow me dice que es mucho código y poco texto. gracias a las personas que me están dando una mano. linda comunidad

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STR 128 // defino cantidad maxima de caracteres string en %s
#define INFO 3     // podemos poner INFO 3 (especificando 3 cosas, asesinatos, muertes, asistencias)
#define USERS 5   // defino la cantidad de usuarios de forma global

/* typedef struct {                       <-- EDX 
    char campeon[MAX_STR];
    int kda[INFO];
} juego;

typedef struct {
    char nombre[MAX_STR];
    int nivel;
    int experiencia;
    juego partida;
} invocador;

*/
typedef struct {    
    char campeon[MAX_STR];
    int AMA[INFO];          // KDA - AMA[INFO] (AMA= asesinatos, muertes, asistencias)
} juego;

typedef struct {
    char nombre[MAX_STR];
    juego partida;
    int usuario;
} invocador;

int main(){
    invocador usuario[USERS]; 
    int AMA_total[INFO],campeon;
    double ratio;
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 1: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[0].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[0].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[0].partida.AMA[0]); // esta perfecto! lo hice bien!
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[0].partida.AMA[1]); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); // lo hice bien! - SEGUIR INTENTANDO CON ESTOS PASOS MIOS Y VER SI FUNCIONA.
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[0].partida.AMA[2]);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[0].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[0].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[0].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 1, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,ratio,usuario[0].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 2: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[1].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[1].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[1].partida.AMA[0]); // esta perfecto! lo hice bien!
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[1].partida.AMA[1]); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); // lo hice bien! - SEGUIR INTENTANDO CON ESTOS PASOS MIOS Y VER SI FUNCIONA.
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[1].partida.AMA[2]);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[1].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[1].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 2, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[1].nombre, ratio, usuario[1].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 3: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[2].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[2].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[2].partida.AMA[0]); // esta perfecto! lo hice bien!
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[2].partida.AMA[1]); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); // lo hice bien! - SEGUIR INTENTANDO CON ESTOS PASOS MIOS Y VER SI FUNCIONA.
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[2].partida.AMA[2]);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[2].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[2].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 3, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[2].nombre, ratio, usuario[2].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 4: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[3].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    scanf("%s", &usuario[3].partida.campeon);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA); // esta perfecto! lo hice bien!
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); // lo hice bien! - SEGUIR INTENTANDO CON ESTOS PASOS MIOS Y VER SI FUNCIONA.
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[3].partida.AMA);
    
    ratio = (double) (usuario[3].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[3].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 4, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[3].nombre, ratio, usuario[3].partida.campeon);
    
    
    printf("\n\n\tDATOS JUGADOR 5: ");
    printf("\n\n\tCual es tu nombre de invocador?: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario[4].nombre);

    printf("\n\n\tCon que campeon jugaste la ultima partida?: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &usuario[4].partida.campeon);
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantos asesinatos has hecho?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[4].partida.AMA); // esta perfecto! lo hice bien!
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas veces moriste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[4].partida.AMA); //scanf("%d", &usuario.j1.partida.AMA[1]); // lo hice bien! - SEGUIR INTENTANDO CON ESTOS PASOS MIOS Y VER SI FUNCIONA.
    
    printf("\n\n\tCuantas asistencias hiciste?: ");
    scanf("%d", &usuario[4].partida.AMA);
    
    ratio= (double) (usuario[4].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[2]) / usuario[4].partida.AMA[1];
    
    printf("%s jugador 5, tu AMA ratio con %s ha sido: %2.lf.\n", usuario[4].nombre, ratio, usuario[4].partida.campeon);
    
//  calculemos el KDA total de los cinco jugadores que han participado en la partida.   
// Para obtener dicho dato es necesario sumar por un lado los asesinatos de los cinco jugadores,
// por otro las muertes y finalmente las asistencias. Asimismo, calcularemos el ratio de ese KDA total.

    AMA_total[0] = usuario[0].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[0] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[0]; //asesinatos de la partida
    AMA_total[1] = usuario[0].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[1] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[1]; // muertes
    AMA_total[2] = usuario[0].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[1].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[2].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[3].partida.AMA[2] + usuario[4].partida.AMA[2]; // asistencias
    
//  ratio = (double)(usuario.partida.kda[0]+usuario.partida.kda[2])/usuario.partida.kda[1]; // Fórmula: (K+A)/D   <- EDX 
    
    ratio = (double) (AMA_total[0] + AMA_total[2]) / AMA_total[1]; // KDA ratio de del KDA total de la partida. Fórmula: (K+A)/D
        
    printf("Usuarios %s, %s, %s, %s y %s, el AMA de tu partida fue %d/%d/d y tu ratio fue %.2lf.\n", usuario[0].nombre,usuario[1].nombre,usuario[2].nombre,usuario[3].nombre,usuario[4].nombre,campeon, ratio);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo el [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos explicando concretamente tu pregunta. Esto y otras cosas más que encontrarás en el link que te cité, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: Dónde defines `usuario` antes de instanciar un `usuario[USERS]`?

Comment: Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/465399/edit) tu pregunta y actualiza el estado de tu problema. Código actualizado, error actualizado, salida esperada.